# R: Changing values in a dataframe without specifying the name of the dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a list named [mylist](/questions/tagged/mylist) which consists of 9 character type elements.

```
>dput(mylist)
list("COG_ONTOLOGY", "GOTERM_BP_DIRECT", "GOTERM_CC_DIRECT", 
"GOTERM_MF_DIRECT", "INTERPRO", "KEGG_PATHWAY", "PIR_SUPERFAMILY", 
"SMART", "UP_KEYWORDS")
```

I also have 9 dataframes with the same names as the elements in [mylist](/questions/tagged/mylist). For example, the dataframe **COG_ONTOLOGY** has the following structure.

```
COG_ONTOLOGY <- data.frame(
  name = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"),
  value = as.numeric(0))
```

In the dataframe **COG_ONTOLOGY**, I need to increment the value of A by 1, but without specifying the name of the dataframe and "A". I tried this but it doesn't seem to work.

```
assign(get(mylist[[1]])[1, "value"], get(mylist[[1]])[1, "value"] + 1)
```

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/8107362). Especially, provide all sample data in a ready-to-copy format, e.g. with `dput()` and use the reprex-package.

Comment: Are the data frame separate entities from the list, i.e. the list is a list of one element names. Whereas the data frames are 9 separate objects?

Comment: @Abhisek, to increment the value of A by 1, doesn’t seem a very meaningful action. Maybe you could consider restate the action you want to  execute over the data frames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would help to have confirmation of your expected output.

Here is one way to approach what I think you are trying to achieve

````r
``` r
COG_ONTOLOGY <- data.frame(
  name = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"),
  value = as.numeric(0))


my_list <- as.list(unlist(c("COG_ONTOLOGY", "GOTERM_BP_DIRECT")))

df <- get(my_list[[1]])

df$value[df$name == "A"] <- df$value[df$name == "A"] + 1

assign(my_list[[1]], df)

COG_ONTOLOGY
#>   name value
#> 1    A     1
#> 2    B     0
#> 3    C     0
#> 4    D     0
#> 5    E     0
````

<sup>Created on 2021-08-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: This solution changes the value associated with A only in the dataframe 'df' and not in the original dataframe 'COG_ONTOLOGY'. Is there a way to get the changes done in the 'COG_ONTOLOGY' dataframe?

Comment: Updated answer, hopefully sufficiently.

Answer (score 0):

We may access components dataframes in lists by indices:

1. To access top-level components of a list of data frames use a double slicing operator  `[[ ]]`
2. to access lower or inner level components of a list use another square `[ ]` along with the double slicing operator `[[ ]]`

Here is an example:

```
COG_ONTOLOGY <- data.frame(
    name = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"),
    value = as.numeric(0))

GOTERM_BP_DIRECT <- data.frame(
    name = c("F", "G", "H", "I", "J"),
    value = as.numeric(0))

mylist <- list(COG_ONTOLOGY, GOTERM_BP_DIRECT)
mylist
mylist[[1]][1,2] <- mylist[[1]][1,2]+1
mylist
```

```
> mylist
[[1]]
  name value
1    A     1
2    B     0
3    C     0
4    D     0
5    E     0

[[2]]
  name value
1    F     0
2    G     0
3    H     0
4    I     0
5    J     0
```

Comment: mylist[[1]][1,2] throws this error: "Error in mylist[[1]][1, 2] : incorrect number of dimensions"

Comment: `mylist` is missing. sorry for that. see my update!!!